# Java Signed Code Applet mixed code Warning Even After Trusted-Library: true

Tags: java, security, applet, signed-applet, mixed-code

Java SE 7 update 21 is throwing a mixed code popup for the applete .

I already added Trusted-Library: true to Manifest.MF and resigned , but its still throwing this popup .

I use some system libraries , do i also need to add Trusted-Library: true in those jars . Am i missing something .

Comment: I don't know what your source of untrusted code is. However, `Trusted-Library` is, as the name suggests, for trusted libraries. It is not suitable for just bunging over a whole applet.

Comment: I figured the issue myself , we had test classes which used Junit jar . I removed the Junit jar and test classes , it worked fine .